# Convert arraylist of arraylists to array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have something like the below:

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] aL = new ArrayList[25];
for (int i = 0; i < aL.length; i++) {
    aL[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

After some logic, I come upon a structure like below:

```
aL[0] = {492,19,183,193};
aL[1] = {13};
aL[2] = {19,56};
aL[3] = {};
aL[4] = {1};
...
```

I want to concatenate `aL` into a new continuous array. The end result for the above example would be `newArray = {492,19,183,193,13,19,56,1,...}`. To note is that I know exactly how many integers there should be in total. I've attempted the below:

```
newArray = new int[100]; //recall the number of ints is defined, ex. 100
int a = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < aL.length; i++) { 
    for (int k = 0; k < aL[i].size(); k++) {
        newArray[a] = aL[i].remove(0);
        a++;
    }
}
```

Upon printing the array, some values are missing. I'm checking how many times the nested loop iterates, and sometimes when `aL[i].size()` is `5` for example, it might only iterate `4` times.

Comment: Please don't modify a list while traversing - replace the "remove" line with `newArray[a] = aL[i].get(k);`

Comment: @Smutje, good point. I didn't think the end condition of a for loop was dynamic, ie. `aL[i].size()` changes as elements are removed and is reflected in the loop conditions.

Comment: It should be `newArray[a] = aL[i].get(k);` instead of `0`.

Comment: @AbishekManoharan true, I changed it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, sorry, I typed null instead of {} in error. I've fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must remove elements from the ArrayLists while iterating over them, you should use a while loop :

```
while (aL[i].size() > 0) {
    newArray[a] = aL[i].remove(0);
    a++;
}
```

However, as commented by Smutja, it's preferable to iterate over the ArrayLists without modifying them.

```
newArray = new int[100]; //recall the number of ints is defined, ex. 100
int a = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < aL.length; i++) { 
    for (int value : aL[i]) {
        newArray[a] = value;
        a++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for( int k = 0; k < aL[i].size() ; k++ ) {
  newArray[a++] = aL[i].remove(0);
}
```

Let's see what happens here !
You start with a list of 5 elements:
- `k == 0` and `aL[i].size() == 5`
0 < 5 so go in the `for` loop, remove the first element of the list and increment k
- `k == 1` and `aL[i].size() == 4`
1 < 4, same
- `k == 2` and `aL[i].size() == 3`
2 < 3, same
- `k == 3` and `aL[i].size() == 2`
3 < 2 is false, so you stop

As you can see, there is only 3 elements removed from the list :)

There are a lot of solution, for example:

```
for( int k = 0; k < aL[i].size() ; k++ ) {
  newArray[a++] = aL[i].get(k);
}
aL[i].clear()
```